# Определение типа фигуры на клеточном поле

Tags: python, алгоритм, распознавание

Помогите найти алгоритм решения следующей задачи:
Есть матрица 50 * 50
В ней обозначены различными буквами различные фигурки тетриса.
Для одной фигурки используется одна буква.
Т.е. одна "палочка" может быть обозначена буквой "а", вторая палочка - буквой "b"
Третья фигура - "кубик" - буквой "c"
...
Нужно считать всю матрицу и на выходе показать сколько фигур какого типа есть в матрице.
...
Даже не представляю куда копать?
Задачу планирую решать на Питоне

Comment: Ну, например, вычислить координаты всех 4 точек, найти минимальный охватывающий прямоугольник. 2х2 - квадрат (O), 1х4 - "палка" (I), 2х3 -- немного повозиться, как в нем точки расположены. Пустые клетки на противоположных углах - Z/S, две рядом - L/J.. Иначе - T. Так сойдет?

Comment: Там есть еще фигурки как "левая змейка", "правая змейка", "буква Т". Фигурки могут быть произвольно повернуты.

Comment: Змейка - это Z/S, а какая из них - ну, поворачивайте в нужное положение и смотрите, какая именно.

Comment: Хотя пока писал комментарий - мысль зашевелилась)... Начать с определения координат. Если разброс по одной стороне = 4 - это однозначно "палочка". Если по обеим сторонам разброс = 2 - это однозначно кубик. ...Мысль иссякла)) Осталось понять как определить фигурку "буква Т", левую и правую змейки. "Поворачивайте и смотрите" - это как?))

Comment: Все, кроме кубика (О) и палочки (I) - вписываются в 3x2. Уже не так много вариантов - можно тупо по клеткам и через if-else проверять, что это. Можно, чтоб уменьшить количество ветвлений, все 2x3 повернуть в 3x2, и смотреть, что это. Какие 2 клетки в прямоугольнике - пустые.